# Unable to edit a currency field in lightning-record-edit-form LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

I have created a simple lightning-record-edit-form on QuoteLineItem object. I have two fields which i'm displaying Quantity & ListPrice. In the record edit form, i'm able to edit the Quantity field, but not the ListPrice(which is a currency field), any pointers to resolve this is much appreciated. Code is as follows :-

```
<lightning-record-edit-form layout-type="Full" record-id={currentRecordId} object-api-name="QuoteLineItem" onsubmit={handleSubmit} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
                            <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
                            <lightning-input-field field-name="Quantity"></lightning-input-field>
                            <lightning-input-field field-name="ListPrice"></lightning-input-field>
                            <br/>

                            <div style="text-align:center;">
                                <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small"
                                                variant="brand"
                                                type="submit"
                                                name="update"
                                                label="Update Record"></lightning-button>
                            </div>
                        </lightning-record-edit-form><br/>
```

I have tried with :- lightning-formatted-number format-style="currency" currency-code="USD" but this dint help.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because List price is taken from the PBE directly and probably should not be edited. There is another field that represents the sale price that should be edited, I believe it is UnitPrice